# Getting error when using abs() relating to indices

Tags: matlab

I have the following for loop:

```
for i = 1:3000
    disp(DCT(key(i, 1), key(i, 2)));

    %Apply formula to HL3 in key location i
    x = sign(DCT(key(i, 1), key(i, 2)));
    y = abs(DCT(key(i, 1), key(i, 2)))^(C-1);
    z = w(1, i);

    %Add result to phi
    phi = phi + (x*y*z);

end
```

I get an error where it says:

```
y = abs(DCT(key(i, 1), key(i, 2)))^(C-1);
```

Saying:

```
    Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in CosineWatermarkDetector (line 25)
    y = abs(DCT(key(i, 1), key(i, 2)))^(C-1);
```

Yet the following code returns the value `-48.6990`:

```
disp(DCT(key(i, 1), key(i, 2)));
```

Can anyone see why?

EDIT: 
Here is the entire code

```
load Key.mat
load watermark.mat

%Select image
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.tif;*.ppm;*.bmp','Picture files (*.tif,*.ppm,*.bmp)'}, 'Pick a image');
path=[pathname,filename];

%Load image from selected path
image = imread(path);

%DWT image
DCT = dct2(image);
figure; imshow(DCT);

%Set value of C
C = 1.7;

%Set values of phi to 0
phi = 0;

for i = 1:3000

    %Apply formula to HL3 in key location i
    x = sign(DCT(key(i, 1), key(i, 2)));
    y = abs(DCT(key(i, 1), key(i, 2)))^(C-1);
    z = w(1, i);

    %Add result to phi
    phi = phi + (x*z);

end
disp(phi);
%If all values of phi are greater than 0 then watermark exists
if (phi > 0)
   disp('Watermark detected');
else
    disp('No watermark detected');
end
```

Comment: @oro777 Is the purpose of the abs() function not to return the value without the sign? So -48.6990 would be turned into 48.6990? That's what the docs say: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html#budexws-4

Comment: Yes sorry, I deleted my comment when I noticed. In your program are you using a variable called abs ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question in the form of a [mcve]

Comment: Post the code related to ```C, DCT, key```

Comment: You likely have shadowed the `abs` function by creating a variable of the same name. `abs(x)` becomes an indexing operation into the variable `abs`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have added all of the code as an edit. As you can see it is very simple and this is the only place that `abs()` is used.

Comment: @AdamCole How should we know, that `abs` isn't probably declared within `Key.mat` or `watermark.mat`?

Comment: What @Hans said, or it’s already defined in the workspace, as you seem to be using scripts rather than functions. In any case, this is much easier for you to figure out than for us. Set a breakpoint in the debugger on the line that throws the error, then when you run the code it will stop there and you can examine the contents of each variable by hovering the mouse over the variable name. Check the value of `abs`.